# What's the root cause of a Swift "Cannot invoke closure" error?

Tags: swift

The following code (stripped for brevity):

```
private lazy var googleViewController = {
    return GoogleSignInViewController()
}()

private lazy var timerViewController = {
    return TimerViewController()
}()
```

produces this error:

> MainViewController.swift:26:6: Cannot invoke closure of type '() -> UIViewController' with an argument list of type '()'

Explicitly typing one of my view controllers fixes the issue:

```
private lazy var timerViewController: TimerViewController = {
    return TimerViewController()
}()
```

However, I don't yet understand the root cause of the error and why this fixes things. I'm assuming it's got something to do with type inference, but not sure about the details. What's going on with my code?

*I do realize I don't need to use closures in the above code, it's meant to be illustrative code*

Comment: Interesting, not sure on this one!

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Swift 3 and Xcode 8. I'm suspicious of the error message and wondering if you stripped some important code. It returns `TimerViewController` so the type of that closure should be `() -> TimerViewController`. It wouldn't infer it as `() -> UIViewController`.

Comment: Can not reproduce either.